# putting JSON key values inside an array and displaying it through $.each loop using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am trying to create an application where i will receive multiple JSON file in below format

```
{
"tname": [
    {
        "project_id" : "SC.0440",
        "project_name" : "AAA - Testing",
        "review_frequency" : "Monthly",
        "planned_ipr_date" : "2016-02-16T18:30:00Z",
        "actual_ipr_date" : "2016-02-16T18:30:00Z",
        "contract" : "G",
        "finance" : "G",
        "delivery" : "G",
        "people" : "G",
        "process" : "G",
        "project_rag" : "G",
        "isms_compliance" : "G",
        "bcms_compliance" : "G",
        "description" : ""
    }
]}
```

And i am taking two select fields in which i will display "tname" in one and on select of "tname" i will display all the key related to it in the other select box.i have done the part where i am getting key values for the first select box and trying to display key values inside it in other select field on change.

I have written a function to get all the key values based on the first selection where filePath() is a function which returns the path of the JSON files

```
function getColumn(keyval){
        var arr = filePath();   
    var colnames = [];
        $.each(arr, function (index, value){ 
            $.getJSON(value,function(result){
                $.each(result,function(key,field){
                    if(key == keyval){
                        $.each(field,function(key,field){
                            $.each(field,function(key,field){
                                colnames.push(key);
                            });
                            return false;
                        }); 
                    }else{
                        return false;
                    }
                });
            });
        });
        return colnames;
    }
```

Now I want to display all the returned key values inside another select box.how i will achieve this using jquery?

Comment: Is there any reason to not pass all values at once and get one (big) json file instead of passing each single returning many json files?

Comment: @Lain I have this merging operation in mind but for now i am trying to solve the mentioned problem for a single json file.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a code sample showing how to populate the 2nd `<select>` with the keys for an object named in the 1st `<select>` e.g. `tname`.

The assumption is that you would be concatenating into the `data` object which enables referencing different object keys for the 2nd `<select>` based on the test:

```
if(data.hasOwnProperty(selectKey)) {
```

Which basically means 'is the value from the 1st select a key in the data object'.

Here is the sample:

```js
var data = {
 "tname": [{
  "project_id": "SC.0440",
  "project_name": "AAA - Testing",
  "review_frequency": "Monthly",
  "planned_ipr_date": "2016-02-16T18:30:00Z",
  "actual_ipr_date": "2016-02-16T18:30:00Z",
  "contract": "G",
  "finance": "G",
  "delivery": "G",
  "people": "G",
  "process": "G",
  "project_rag": "G",
  "isms_compliance": "G",
  "bcms_compliance": "G",
  "description": ""
 }]
};

$("#items1").on("change", function() {
  var selectKey = $(this).val();
  $("#items2").empty();
  if(data.hasOwnProperty(selectKey)) {
    $.each(data[selectKey][0], function(k, v) {
      $("#items2").append("<option value='" + k + "'>" + k + "</option>");
    }); 
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="select1">
  <select id="items1">
    <option value="foo">foo</option>
    <option value="tname">tname</option>
    <option value="bar">bar</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div id="select2">
  <select id="items2">
  </select>
</div>
```